# Using ArcGIS to extend a polygon in one direction up to the edge of another polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.4

I have two shapefiles: the first containing a route defined by a single polygon (black line in the image below), the second containing a series of between 1000 and 4000 small polygons located somewhere inside the larger polygon (green and pink boxes).

[image]

I would like to extend each of the small polygons in the direction perpendicular to the route, so that they become long polygons that end at the edge of the outer polygon. These new polygons don't necessarily have to span the entire width of the route polygon, for example where they appear on a bend, as shown below:

[image]

I am using ArcGIS 10.4.1 for Desktop with an Advanced license. I've also got access to a Spatial Analyst license. Is what I want possible, and if so how do I do it? I could also use any freely available software other than ArcGIS if that would make this possible.

-----Update-----

Following the suggestion from @Hornbydd and @FelixIP to use Arc's [Euclidean Allocation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/euclidean-allocation.htm) tool (available with a Spatial Analyst license), I now have what I was aiming to produce, as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: While possible, it's unlikely you'll find such a tool sitting in a shelf. This means you'll need to choose a development language (C++/C#/Python) and start coding. Given the bends in the green polygon chain, you'll need to decide how to handle line extension.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mention it because I tried to make the question as simple as possible, but I do code in Python and have already made extensive use of the ArcPy module, so any solutions that make use of this would be ideal.

Comment: It's asking a bit much to expect the good folk of GIS SE to code this for you. In fact, we have a policy to *not* do so. If, however, you start the process and get stuck, then you can post the relevant portion of code, and we can try to untangle you.

Comment: Sorry @Vince, I didn't mean to ask for a full solution or a lot of anyone else's effort - I'm an experienced coder, but extremely new to GIS. I was looking to see if there was a GIS tool that would get me some of the way there that I could incorporate into some code, or even if anyone could suggest some tools for me to investigate further.

Comment: @MapHound I'd like to do this for a few different files, each containing between 1000 and 4000 polygons.

Comment: Please remember to [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification.

Comment: The (pink) polygon in your example is fairly trivial.  Please sketch out expected results for the polygons where the path bends, and maybe explain the logic used to draw it.

Comment: This isn't an Intro to GIS task, but if you work the problem in iterations, it can be solved. First, structure a script to iterate the polygons in a DA SearchCursor. Then add an InsertCursor to write the first FC to a new FC. Then identify the edge vertices  (left and right). Then, construct a line from the edge to the outer line (past it, then intersect). Finally, add the three vertices on each side to the output polygons.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall Thanks for the query - I'm still thinking through what I'm trying to achieve, so it was helpful to think of an answer. I've updated the second image and explanation in the question to illustrate this better.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for your comment, that's a really helpful flow - I'll work on the steps you suggest and provide an answer if I get somewhere with it.

Comment: Just to throw a bone and\or red herring into the pot are you aware of the extend line tool? Search help. If you can figure out how to explode the central polygons into their sides you could use that tool as a potential solution. But it may be easier to manipulate geometries and use the near tool alongside cursors as @Vince has suggested?

Comment: I don't know if these will help but ArcGIS has a Create Points at Corners of Polygon sample (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4d77199a45c340aaa59ccb9948380038) and ETGeowizards has a Perpendiculars to Polylines tool in its points group that you could apply to those points.  The ET tool, however, is not one of its free tools.

Comment: Euclidean allocation will solve it easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the simplest approach with zero coding I think @FelixIP has nailed it! Simply use the Euclidean Allocation tool, making sure you set your outer boundary as the mask and processing extent, then choose a sensible cell size to produce a smooth raster which you can then turn back into a polygon.

Here is the output of the Allocation tool built from the inner hashed polygons but constrained (masked) by the outer black line:

[image: Euclidean Allocation]

It would be a simple matter of converting the raster back to a polygon featureclass. This approach may introduce a slight zig-zag edge to the final polygons because they are derived from a raster, if you are prepared to accept that then this problem is reduced to running two tools, Euclidean Allocation then raster to polygon.

Comment: To reduce the zig-zag, just buffer your boundary for the Euclidean Allocation, and then clip by the original.

Comment: This is the kind of solution that I was hoping would be possible - it's produced exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

There are some good suggestions and partial answers buried in the comments, so I'm quoting/paraphrasing them here:

### @Vince's suggestions:

While possible, it's unlikely you'll find such a tool sitting in a shelf. This means you'll need to choose a development language (C++/C#/Python) and start coding. Given the bends in the green polygon chain, you'll need to decide how to handle line extension.

This isn't an Intro to GIS task, but if you work the problem in iterations, it can be solved.

- First, structure a script to iterate the polygons in a DA SearchCursor.
- Then add an InsertCursor to write the first FC to a new FC. Then identify the edge vertices (left and right).
- Then, construct a line from the edge to the outer line (past it, then
  intersect).

---

### @Hornbydd's suggestions:

If you can figure out how to explode the central polygons into their sides you could use the [extend line tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/editing-toolbox/extend-line.htm). But it may be easier to manipulate geometries and use the near tool alongside cursors as @Vince has suggested.

---

### @johns' suggestions:

ArcGIS has a [Create Points at Corners of Polygon sample](http://arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4d77199a45c340aaa59ccb9948380038) and [ETGeowizards](https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/ToolBox/toolbox_userguide.htm) has a Perpendiculars to Polylines tool in its points group that you could apply to those points. The ET tool, however, is not one of its free tools.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a way to do this with arcpy, but I'm not aware of any.

So here's how I would do it:

Using ArcObjects, write a C# routine that follows these steps:

Create a new empty polygon featureclass. Open an insertion cursor on it.

Retrieve the MapTopology from the TopologyExtension, then build the full extent.

Get a polyline representing the boundary of the polygon (using ITopologicalOperator3.Boundary).

Open a search cursor on your small polygons.

Loop through each small polygon.  For each polygon feature call `ITopologyGraph.GetParentEdges`. From those parents, find the two edges that have both a left and a right parent edge.  For those edges, find the points on the boundary closest to them (using `IProximityOperator`).

Create a new polygon feature.  Populate the new feature's geometry with a polygon formed using `IPointCollection`.

Add points to the new polygon. `IPointCollection.Add` the point on the boundary polygon, then add the points in the parentedge where the small polygon is on the parent's right. Then add points between the two points on the outer boundary, then the other edge, then the points between the two boundary points. (`ICurve.GetSubcurve` using points from `ICurve.QueryPointandDistance`)

Verify the geometry is simple (`ITopologicalOperator3.IsKnownSimple = false` then `ITopologicalOperator.Simplify()`).

Insert the polygon feature into the output featureclass.