# Split Polygon to match length of lines with QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, features, splitting

I have a large polygon shapefile with many features (green), representing waterbody outlines, and a line shapefile (brown) representing river sections. I now want to split the polygon features into smaller parts that match those river sections, but don't know how to do it properly.

[image]

I don't mind the software, might be QGIS or ArcGIS, even a Python-script, but let's focus on QGIS for now.  Any suggestions?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297533/using-arcgis-to-extend-a-polygon-in-one-direction-up-to-the-edge-of-another-poly#comment478505_297533

Comment: If I understand what you're looking for this may help: for every line feature (granted some of them don't intersect any polygons) create a flat (not rounded) buffer (you have to decide the buffer distance) and intersect the buffer with the waterbody polygon shapefile. That may create something like what you're looking for. Do you guys think that makes sense?

Comment: Please decide which of the GIS products mentioned you want to ask about.  By asking about more than one you are effectively asking multiple questions which goes against the [Tour]. You should then describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Proceed as follows, 1) cut the lines with polygons 2) polygons and lines into points 3) merge point layers into a common one and run the delone triangulation tool 4) select those polygons that intersect with your source lines 5) merge polygons, if I understood your question this method will bring good luck (QGIS tool will solve your problem) ...

Comment: @Cyril - Thanks, did it in a similar way and it seemed to work.

Comment: Moderators closed your question and so I formulated my answer in the comments, I'm glad for you that you have coped with its task, good luck